# After Umount -f -a pc not recognize hdd

Tags: 13.04, bios

I executed umount -a -f / to unmount all devices.after restarting system i can not see ubuntu choice of grub2,i mean grub2 Does not come.i aenter code herem alone with the bios of dell inspiron 15r . How can i make pc recognize grub2 menu.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from rescue CD (or flash disk) and do Rescue Mode.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/rescue.html